# Prove H(T) has an exponential distribution with mean one

Tags: probability, exponential-distribution

Let $T$ be a continuous non-negative random variable with cumulative hazard function $H(·)$.
Prove $H(T)$ has an exponential distribution with mean one.

Completely lost at this point.

This should help:
[image: imgage]

Comment: I think it's straight forward, but I'm missing something.

Comment: Please do [not use pictures for critical portions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189)
of your post. Pictures may not be legible,
cannot be searched and are not view-able to some,
such as those who use screen readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got it, please comment if you think this is correct.

-Thank you

[image: answer]

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax.
For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation),
[mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020),
[main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559)
and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).